# What are the ways of acquiring viveka (discriminative faculty) according to the scriptures?

Tags: scripture, ramcharitmanas, satsang

For eg:-

Goswami Tulsidas-Ji in his Ramcharitmanas says-

> बिनु सत्संग विवेक न होई। रामकृपा बिनु सुलभ न सोई।।

> Without satsang, discrimination is not awakened and without Rama's grace it's not possible to hear satsang.

So what are the other ways other than Satsang for acquiring viveka?

Comment: It seems to be an अर्थवाद • (arthavāda), praise or eulogy, of satsang to attain viveka, which is natural , easy to follow for most of the common people , suggested as part of bhakti sutraas.

Though, karma yoga, Patanjali yoga sutras, upasana , etc  could be the stepping stone to achieve viveka.

Comment: similar view as part of 'Bhaja Govindam',                        satsaṅgatvē nissaṅgatvaṃ
nissaṅgatvē nirmōhatvam ।
nirmōhatvē niśchalatattvaṃ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the different kinds of Viveka and how can we develop them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-viveka-and-how-can-we-develop-them)

Comment: Please try to translate the verse into English and write along with it, if possible.

Comment: @hanugm you can check now.

Comment: @Harsh Near that chaupayee only it is written that all good works in world should be thought of the result of satsang, and maybe it gives examples of nArad, ghatjoni etc